# Woocommerce Custom Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I need help with a custom email hook for woocommerce.

I am trying to send a different email depending on product ID whenever a product is completed.

My code, which is not working, is as follows:

```
/**************
DIFFERENT MESSAGES FOR DIFFERENT PRODUCTS
****************/

//hook our function to the new order email
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details',     'uiwc_email_order_details_products', 1, 4);

function uiwc_email_order_details_products($order, $admin, $plain, $email) {
 $status = $order->get_status();

 // checking if it's the order status we want
  if ( $status == "completed" ) {
   $items = $order->get_items();

    if ( $item['product_id'] == "3181") {
      echo __( '<strong>IMPORTANT - NEXT STEP:</strong><br>To get started, please follow <a href="https:XXXXX">this link</a> to complete the Policies form.<br><br>This is a really important first step, and only takes about 5 minutes.  After completeing the Policies form, you will receive additional instructions on next steps.<br><br>Congratulations! Let your journey begin.<br><br>', 'uiwc' );
  }

   elseif ( $item['product_id'] == "3223") {
      echo __( '<strong>IMPORTANT - NEXT STEP:</strong><br>Differnet product so differenct email....<br><br>', 'uiwc' );
  }
}  
}
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking for help, it is important to not just say "this is not working" but to explain what your expected result is and how the results produced by your code differ from that. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you mean by product is completed ? Do you mean order is completed ?

Comment: @Nick (does that work on SO?) Thanks for the advice.  Next time I will be more descriptive in my problem statement.  Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @melvin after re-reading my question, you're right - it doesn't make sense.  You did guess it though, I meant when the order is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code, instead try the following

```
//hook our function to the new order email
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'custom_email_order_details', 4, 4 );
function custom_email_order_details( $order, $admin, $plain, $email ) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    // checking if it's the order status we want
    if ( $order->has_status('completed') ) {
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            if ( $item->get_product_id() == '3181' ) {
                echo __( '<strong>IMPORTANT - NEXT STEP:</strong><br>To get started, please follow <a href="https://xxxxxx">this link</a> to complete the Policies form.<br><br>This is a really important first step, and only takes about 5 minutes. After completeing the Policies form, you will receive additional instructions on next steps.<br><br>Congratulations! Let your journey begin.<br><br>', $domain );
                break;
            }
            elseif ( $item->get_product_id() == '3223' ) {
                echo __( '<strong>IMPORTANT - NEXT STEP:</strong><br>Differnet product so differenct email....<br><br>', $domain );
                break;
            }
        } 
    }  
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: thank you so much for the help.  This was exactly what I was looking for and it worked perfectly.  What you didn't see was the 5 hours of trying and retrying this hook with no success before a hail mary to SO, so thanks again.  I do have one last question though... if I wanted to add additional products, I could copy and paste the last 'elseif' statement and change the productID accordingly, correct?